# Resources are not supported in serialized data MongoDB JMSSerializer

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Im trying to develop an API (based on DoctrineMongoDBBundle and FOSRestBundle) that stores all the hole data in MongoDB, recovers it, and shows it using FOSRest.

When I try to show a list of objects stored in database this is what i'm getting:

> "message": "Resources are not supported in serialized data. Path:
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler -> Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger ->
>   Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Logger\Logger ->
>   Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Logger\AggregateLogger ->
>   Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Configuration -> Doctrine\MongoDB\Connection
>   -> Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor", "class": "JMS\Serializer\Exception\RuntimeException",

My config.yml for FOS is this:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

And that's my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/services.{_format}", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @REST\View()
 */
public function getServicesAction($_format){
    $services = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()
        ->getRepository('RadmasOpen010Bundle:Service')
        ->findAll();

    return $services;
}
```

I tried to return a well formed Array, and no error were displayed, as well as if I join all the Service objects into an Array.

I tried to solve it installing Mongo PHP extension with PECL, changing some configs, but nothing has changed.

Anyone knows what cound be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a colection of RadmasOpen010Bundle:Service documents, you MUST call the method "toArray" after calling find method from repository or getQuery method from query builder

```
/**
 * @Route("/services.{_format}", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @REST\View()
 */
public function getServicesAction($_format){
    $services = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()
        ->getRepository('RadmasOpen010Bundle:Service')
        ->findAll()->toArray();

    return $services;
}
```

also you can call array_values($services) for correct serialization of exclude strategy